# Where can I download the Ubuntu Touch developer preview?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Hi where exactly is the download link for the preview? all I can see to download is the factory firmware for the 4 devices but no actual download link for the preview.

Answer (score 2):

The steps mentioned in [Install page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) state that you need to install `phablet-tools` and other tools on your system to flash the device. This fetches the most recent image and downloads to your device.

**More information**

- [OMGUbuntu - How To Install Ubuntu Touch Preview on Nexus Devices](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-install-ubuntu-phone-tablet-preview-on-nexus-devices)
- [Video - How to Install Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview on Nexus Devices](http://youtu.be/8Y5C66BOPbs)

Answer (score 1):

The Install page directions assume you are installing from Ubuntu, so you don't need the direct link. But the direct link is http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/quantal/mwc-demo/.